# Call default camera app in Windows Universal App

Tags: c#, mobile, camera, photo, win-universal-app

I'm developing a Windows Universal app. I'd like the user to be able to launch default camera app and get the taken photo in my app page.
In android this can be achieved with three lines of Java:

```
 Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
 if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
     startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
 }
```

I don't want to create my custom camera, it's an overkill for my purpose.

Answer (score 0):

No need to create your own UI. Try CameraCaptureUI from the Windows.Media.Capture Namespace.
Code looks like this:

```
CameraCaptureUI dialog = new CameraCaptureUI();         
StorageFile file = await dialog.CaptureFileAsync(CameraCaptureUIMode.Photo);
```

Also check this Sample:
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/CameraCaptureUI-Sample-845a53ac/sourcecode?fileId=43599&pathId=1212418128